# How to customize search results color in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the color of file names which is shown on screenshot.

[image]

Comment: look in the list of defined colors and change it in your settings, if no color found add a feature request

Comment: If you're willing to use the [Custom CSS and JS plugin](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css), you can use the `.filematch` class.  For example, point the extension at a css file containing `.filematch { color:red; }`.

Comment: @MikePatrick thanks, looks like there is no native way to do it.